# How select cities from country (geopandas)?

Tags: python, geopandas

I would like to select cities from polygon (Poland), but filter points in polygon doesn't work.
I have code:

```
import geopandas
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world=world[world.name == 'Poland']
cities = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
world['geometry']
cities['geometry']
c=world['geometry'].contains(cities['geometry'])
cities[c.values]
```

Unfortunately the results are only "False". Could You help me ? Why "contains" is not working ?
Is another way to select cities in geopandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `read_file()` with `mask` argument or an `sjoin()` should be the same.  Currently due to an issues with compatibility of **geos** and **gdal** versions these are not the same on my environment.

```
import geopandas

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
world = world[world.name == "Poland"]
cities = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
cities = geopandas.read_file(
    geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"), mask=world
)
```